# Can Apache Drill handle KMS encrypted files?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-drill

I've been experimenting with Apache drill and can successfully query a CSV file in my S3 bucket that is not KMS encrypted.  But, when I try to query the exact same file that has been KMS encrypted, I get an error.

Is Apache capable of handling KMS encrypted files?  And, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Drill doesn't support it yet. Feel free to create a Jira ticket for it with providing details and use cases. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL